# Effect of early pay off and using again for credit card

Tags: credit-score, credit

I'm using below 30% of available credit and paying off all amount early. What will happen if I use some amount lets say again below 30% and pay it off again before the due date.

Does it considered as below 30% credit utilization or 60%?

How is the effect to credit score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing happens, the credit agencies only receive information about **maximum** utilization, not cumulative. Only 30% will be reported, because that's the maximum utilization of the credit line at any given time that you're reaching.

Comment: We've answered this a number of times. Utilization is reported at the time the bill is cut. I've run up to 60%, paid before the bill is cut and got dinged for 0% utilization.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer your answer is contradicting littleadv's answer can you guys give some links to read more...?

Comment: See my answer to http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/16862/to-what-extent-should-i-seek-additional-credit-how-much-is-enough/ I believe that will clarify my position.

Answer (score 2):

I am a user of CreditKarma, who offers a score fed from Transunion data. The utilization is reported once per month, the number that appears on the bill. If the ideal utilization is greater than 0, but less than 20%, you have to monitor the cards' usage if you have a low limit. For example, a $5000 line may seem all you need, but charge over $1000 and it will impact your score that cycle. Paying a bit before the bill is cut to bring it below $1000 will keep your score from fluctuating.